# Selecting an manipulating an existing element with jQuery SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, svg, jquery-svg

All of the examples on jQuery SVG's website seem to be geared toward building an SVG object in javascript and building new elements within it. It *doesn't* talk much about manipulating existing markup.

**PROBLEM:**

I have an existing SVG object with events wired up to javascript functions. I want to take the event target (in this case, an SVG Path element) and `.animate()` it using jQuery SVG.

*However*, simply `$(myElement).animate()` doesn't seem to work. The issue at hand seems to be that `$(myElement)` doesn't accept SVG objet arguments, or something.

Oddly the animate completion callback seems to work, but NO animation type I try to do with it works at all.

I'm not convinced it's properly recognizing the event target as an SVG `<path>`.

Even directly manipulating the attributes of the path don't seem to work (using `.attr()`)

I know factually that `myElement` is a valid SVG path because if I use basic JS DOM techniques like changing the class with `.setAttribute()`, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this one could help you out: http://keith-wood.name/svgRef.html#support
Just an example taken from this page:
$(shape).animate({svgFill: 'lightblue'}, 2000);